# GSP g:select option default selection

Tags: html, grails, gsp

Is there any possibility to select a option field by default in a `g:select` tag?

I only saw the "noSelection" parameter in the documentation.

```
<g:select name="user.age" from="${18..65}" value="${age}"
      noSelection="['':'-Choose your age-']"/>
```

But I need a default selection from the data I received.

For example 18..65 is my range and I want to select 20 as default selection.

Is that possible or do I have to do this with javascript?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `value` attribute does exactly that. From the Grails documentation:

> value (optional) - The current selected value that evaluates equals() to true for one of the elements in the from list.

So, if you want to select "20" if your `age` model variable is null, just do

```
<g:select name="user.age" from="${18..65}" value="${age ?: 20}"
      noSelection="['':'-Choose your age-']"/>
```

Comment: First: thanks for your answer.
Now I got it right. Your closure helped me out. So I just want to put 20 as default that means I need to put "20" in the value attribute without closure.

With the closure "$(age?:20)" I got only "20" as default if age is not set.

Comment: It's actually not a closure, but rather an EL expression. And yes, if you always want to select 20 (eg. if this is a create view), just set "20" as value. I'm not entirely sure, but maybe you will still have to place it in ${} for Grails to interpret it as an integer rather than a string (ie. value="${20}").

Comment: BTW, `age ?: 20` is short for `age ? age : 20`, which is short for `if(age != null) age; else 20;`

Comment: ? and ?: use groovy truth which means 0, empty string, empty list, empty map are all false as well...